# Close windows program before opening it again

Tags: python, windows

My goal is to open images for a certain amount of time, and then display another random image after that.

Windows opens up every image as a new instance, so I would like to close the old image before a new image is opened.

What is the absolute simplest way of automating this. The simple program works pretty much as intended, except for this one thing of not closing the old images.

```
cont = True

#### Time Functions
def waits(): # basic wait
    time.sleep(s)
def waitm(): # basic wait
    time.sleep(s)
def waitl(): # basic wait
    time.sleep(s)
def wait(): # wait between notes
    time.sleep(wt)
```

```
g3 = Image.open(imd+"g3.png")
a3 = Image.open(imd+"a3.png")
b3 = Image.open(imd+"b3.png")
c4 = Image.open(imd+"c4.png")
d4 = Image.open(imd+"d4.png")
e4 = Image.open(imd+"e4.png")
f4s = Image.open(imd+"f4s.png")
g4 = Image.open(imd+"g4.png")
```

```
def randomNotes():
    GM_s_o = (g3, a3, b3, c4, d4, e4, f4s, g4) # G-major scale, open string # f
    r_note = random.choice(GM_s_o)

    r_note.show()
    waits()

def waitTime():
    global wt

    print("Choose wait time.")
    answer = input("s for short, m for medium, l for long.")

    if answer == "s":
        wt = 3
        return wt
    if answer == "m":
        wt = 6
        return wt
    if answer == "l":
        wt = 10
        return wt
    else:
        waitTime()
```

```
def program():
    global cont

    if cont == True:



        randomNotes()
        randomNotes()
        randomNotes()
        randomNotes()
        randomNotes()
        randomNotes()
        randomNotes()


        print("Would you like to continue?")
        answer = input("y for yes, n for no.")

        if answer == "y":
            cont = True
            program()

        if answer == "n":
            cont = False


    if cont == False:
        exit()
```

```
#### Actual

waitTime()
program()
```

Comment: You can try to determine what process was spawned after calling `open` (this can change depending on the default image viewing program configured on the machine), then kill that process

Comment: How would I go about doing this? The program is Windows Photos .

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. This isn't an optimal program since it's not distributable really, but it works for my personal use. Thanks! Learned something new!